# Have a break line in HTML element value

Tags: html, encoding

I want to have a break in a button value on chrome, which used to work fine till their last update 3 weeks ago, since then, that stopped working:

```
<input type="button" value="line &#10; break" />
```

JSFiddle :

[No line break](https://jsfiddle.net/a3q52qtj/)

Does anyone have any new ideas to get this line break in an element value ??

Comment: You do that in order to have 2 lines of text inside the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input[type="button"] {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: left;
  width: 6ch;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="line break" />
```

You can use `"white-space: normal"` if you don't want to use `<button>` The width of the button could be set to the length of your longest word by the unit measurement `ch` one `ch` = width of one letter.

Comment: Thank you , adding that CSS to the input indeed created a new line where I needed (After &#10;) Thank you !

Comment: Your'e most welcome, sir. I added some extra styles just in case the `whitespace: normal` looks funky.

Comment: It definitely solved my issue. But i'm thinking, if for a reason i wanted a break of line in the value of that button regardless of the input width, that would be impossible eh ?? I don't know why Chrome updated their browser to ignore &#10;

Comment: Yes you'd have to set the width of button. In my update, the longest word is "break" which is 5 letters, so I set it to 6ch which is 6 letter widths long. Only the Chrome team knows why they do the things they do, us mere mortals could not comprehend.

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```html
<button>
<span>Line 1</span><br/>
<span>Line 2</span>
</button>
```

Comment: That's a cool idea, but i need to keep using <input> because it implemented too deep in my scripts,css etc..Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
<input type="button" />
```

You should use the `button` tag instead, which in turn you can use the HTML `<br/>` tag to make your line break. This should work on all browsers as this is a valid HTML code.

```
<button>
   Line<br/> 
   Break
</button>
```